# How to merge one pdf into another pdf file in swift 3.0.?

Tags: pdf, swift3

I am using this code.but pdfDocumentRef3 coming nil. so its crashing.
Please let me know where i am doing wrong. 
let cachesDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
 let filePath1 = "(cachesDirectoryPath)/ShowPdf_(self.airportMainId).pdf"
 let filePath2 = "(cachesDirectoryPath)/ImagePdf_(self.airportMainId).pdf
 let filePath3 = cachesDirectoryPath.appending("/Combine_(self.airportMainId).pdf")

self.mergeTwoPDF(filePath1: filePath1, filePath2: filePath2, combinePath: filePath3 )

```
func mergeTwoPDF(filePath1: String, filePath2: String, combinePath: String) {

    let pdfURL1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath1)

    let pdfURL2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath2)

    let pdfURL3 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: combinePath)

    let pdfDocumentRef1 = CGPDFDocument(pdfURL1 as CFURL)

    let pdfDocumentRef2 = CGPDFDocument(pdfURL2 as CFURL)

    let pdfDocumentRef3 = CGPDFDocument(pdfURL3 as CFURL)

    let numberOfPages1 = pdfDocumentRef1!.numberOfPages

    let numberOfPages2 = pdfDocumentRef2!.numberOfPages

    let writeContext = CGContext(pdfDocumentRef3 as! CFURL, mediaBox: nil, nil)

    var page: CGPDFPage?
    var mediaBox: CGRect
    for var i in 0..<numberOfPages1 {
            page = pdfDocumentRef1!.page(at: i)
            mediaBox = page!.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
            writeContext!.beginPage(mediaBox: &mediaBox)
        writeContext!.drawPDFPage(page!)
        writeContext!.endPage()
    }
    for var i in 0..<numberOfPages2 {
        page = pdfDocumentRef2!.page(at: i)
        mediaBox = page!.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
        writeContext!.beginPage(mediaBox: &mediaBox)
        writeContext!.drawPDFPage(page!)
        writeContext!.endPage()
    }

    writeContext!.closePDF();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pdfDocumentRef3 is nil because the file does not exist.

You should use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(combinePath, CGRect.zero, nil)
let writeContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
```